# Creating Fixture for CollectionFS File

Tags: meteor, collectionfs

Is there a way to generate fixture for a CollectionFS [File](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/blob/devel/packages/file/api.md)? Normally it would have to be uploaded through a browser, but I would like to generate fixtures from local files.